# Iterate list of numbers

Tags: python

I have a list of 13 numbers, each of them can be equal any number from 1 to 9.

I need to look over all possible variants of these numbers in the list: when `number1=1` and `number2=1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9` (exclusive 0), and so on. Then I need to do the same for `number1=2` and so on.

I can't quite comprehend how to do it - apparently through 'for' cycle?

```
for x in range(1,10):
    A=[x for i in range(13)]
for i in range(len(A)):
    for t in range(1,10):
        A[i]=t
        print A
```

This doesn't work out.

Comment: Use `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `itertools.product`.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(1, 10), repeat=2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing it for 13 numbers. Why? Take a look:

```
>>> len(list(product(range(1, 10), repeat=2)))
81
```

9^2 = 81. So to compute it for 13, you would need to compute 9^13 tuples with length 13. That will take quite a while.

Luckily `itertools.product` returns a generator object, so you *can* iterate through the values one by one if you wish. Just don't try to turn it into a list.